# can I define in CSS look of DIV being empty? (no children elements)

Tags: html, css

Is it somehow possible to define certain look for DIV being empty, i.e having no accessors inside (no nested elements) without need of using JS, just using pure CSS?

Comment: Yes. What have you tried and what went wrong?

Comment: I was dealing only with JS/jQuery staff and have no idea how to deal with it in CSS.

Comment: what kind of 'behavior' ?

Comment: @FranciscoCorralesMorales `behaviour` changed to `look` for being more accurate.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes that's what the [`:empty`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:empty) pseudo-class is for.

From the MDN docs:

> The `:empty` pseudo-class represents any element that has no children at
>   all. Only element nodes and text (including whitespace) are
>   considered. Comments or processing instructions do not affect whether
>   an element is considered empty or not.

Comment: `#selected-sources:empty` will be corect way of accesing it in stylsheets or only by class access is possible?

Comment: @andi you can use any type of selector before `:empty`

Comment: OK. I had have some problems with SASS and django templates but now it works. Problematic thing is that it treats some `\n` or whitespaces as content...

Comment: @andi yes `:empty` is picky that way, whitespace is considered a node